# Relayout children in CustomViewGroup

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-viewgroup

I have a Custom ViewGroup and I override onLayout method to layout its children. Every time onLayout called just some of children need to be layout.
The problem is when I call requestLayout() the children that i don't layout them are shown from last call.

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {

    .
    .
    .
    // calculate a and b parameter

    for (int i = a; i < b ; i++) {
        getChildAt(i).layout(l, t ,r ,b );
    }


}
```

The question is How hide a child from layout or clear ViewGroup and relayout children ?
or any other solution ...

Comment: Besides keeping a SparseArray<Boolean> of what should be visible and what not, there's no other "clean" way to do this. But why would you lay-out only some children? For speed? Think again and notice that leaving some of the children out might have some undesirable effects.

Comment: It's like a listView so some children are out of screen. Also position of each child need math calculation. I lay out children manually and animate with a Runnable and call requestLayout (). If you can't understand what I need I can post all of the source.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone still has this problem, my solution was to address ALL the child views in onLayout:

- set visibility = View.VISIBLE and call layout on the ones I want to show
- set visibility = View.GONE for the ones I want to hide (and don't call layout on them). You can't just not lay them out if they are already there.

Alternatively, [others](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12643317) have suggested you can override onDraw and clear the canvas:

```
 override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {

        // clear if new layout to get rid of unused views:
        if(clearCanvas) {  
            canvas?.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
            clearCanvas = false;
        }

        super.onDraw(canvas)
    }
```

Set `clearCanvas = true` in onLayout, when you know things have changed, and call `invalidate()`.

However, I was not able to get it to call my onDraw() function ever! So, while this seems cleaner, there's something I'm still missing...